# How to filter elements of a [][]string slice in Golang?

Tags: csv, go, duplicates, slice

First of all i'm new here and i'm trying to learn Golang. I would like to check my csv file (which has 3 values; type, maker, model) and create a new one and after a filter operation i want to write new data(filtered) to the created csv file. Here is my code so you can understand me more clearly.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    //openning my csv file which is vehicles.csv
    recordFile, err := os.Open("vehicles.csv")
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println("An error encountered ::", err)
    }
    //reading it
    reader := csv.NewReader(recordFile)
    vehicles, _ := reader.ReadAll()
    //creating a new csv file
    newRecordFile, err := os.Create("newCsvFile.csv")
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println("An error encountered ::", err)
    }
    //writing vehicles.csv into the new csv
    writer := csv.NewWriter(newRecordFile)
    err = writer.WriteAll(vehicles)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("An error encountered ::", err)
    }
}
```

After i build it, it is working this way. It reads and writes the all data to new created csv file. But the problem here is, i want to filter duplicates of readed csv which is **vehicles**, i am creating another function (outside of the main function) to filter duplicates but i can't do it because **vehicles** 's type is **[][]string**, i searched the internet about filtering duplicates but all i found is int or string types. What i want to do is create a function and call it before WriteAll operation so WriteAll can write the correct (duplicates filtered) data into new csv file. Help me please!!
I appreciate any answer.
Happy coding!

Comment: How do you define a duplicate? Is it when all three elements of the slice are equal? If so, you can create a `map[[3]string]struct{}` to store all processed vehicles so you can look them up. For a more generic solution, you can write a slice comparison function and lookup if the same slice was seen before

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes i mean all three elements of the slice are equal.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on how you define "uniqueness", but in general there are a few parts of this problem.

What is unique?

1. All fields must be equal
2. Only some fields must be equal
3. Normalize some or all fields before comparing

You have a few approaches for applying your uniqueness, including:

1. You can use a map, keyed by the "pieces" of uniqueness, requires O(N) state
2. You can sort the records and compare with the prior record as you iterate, requires O(1) state but is more complicated

You have two approaches for filtering and outputting:

1. You can build a new slice based on the old one using a loop and write all at once, this requires O(N) space
2. You can write the records out to the file as you go if you don't need to sort, this requires O(1) space

I think a reasonably simple and performant approach would be to pick (1) from the first, (1) from the second, and (2) from the third, which together would look like:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "errors"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    input, err := os.Open("vehicles.csv")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("opening input file: %s", err)
    }

    output, err := os.Create("vehicles_filtered.csv")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("creating output file: %s", err)
    }
    defer func() {
        // Ensure the file is closed at the end of the program
        if err := output.Close(); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("finalizing output file: %s", err)
        }
    }()

    reader := csv.NewReader(input)
    writer := csv.NewWriter(output)

    seen := make(map[[3]string]bool)
    for {
        // Read in one record
        record, err := reader.Read()
        if errors.Is(err, io.EOF) {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("reading record: %s", err)
        }
        if len(record) != 3 {
            log.Printf("bad record %q", record)
            continue
        }

        // Check if the record has been seen before, skipping if so
        key := [3]string{record[0], record[1], record[2]}
        if seen[key] {
            continue
        }
        seen[key] = true

        // Write the record
        if err := writer.Write(record); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("writing record %d: %s", len(seen), err)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am checking all 3 values at the same time. Type, Maker and Model. This code is working but my csv file has 9K+ rows. But when i run this code it creates a new csv file and doesn't get duplicates (as expected) but it stops on 1223th row. Is there any problem with timing?